# all possible combinations of n-sets keeping the set sizes

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, combinations, combinatorics

I have a list of sets:

```
const sets = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9, 10]];
```

The items in the sets are a set themselves, in this case 1-10.

I want to produce all possible combinations of those items in the given set layout. So:

```
[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10]
[5,2,3,4], [1,6,7,8], [9,10]
[5,6,3,4], [1,2,7,8], [9,10]
...
```

i.e. I get a new combination by swapping each item in a group with an item in another group. Note that I'm not trying to get permutations, so the order of items within each set is unimportant.

So far I've got:

```
type Index = [number, number];

function swap(sets: number[][], index1: Index, index2: Index) {
  const temp = sets.map((g) => g.slice());
  temp[index1[0]][index1[1]] = sets[index2[0]][index2[1]];
  temp[index2[0]][index2[1]] = sets[index1[0]][index1[1]];
  return temp;
}

function setCombinations(sets: number[][]): number[][][] {
  const combinations = [];
  // Include the original combination
  combinations.push(sets);

  for (let s1 = 0; s1 < sets.length - 1; s1++) {
    for (let s2 = 1; s2 < sets.length; s2++) {
      for (let i1 = 0; i1 < sets[s1].length; i1++) {
        for (let i2 = 0; i2 < sets[s2].length; i2++) {
          combinations.push(swap(sets, [s1, i1], [s2, i2]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return combinations;
}

const sets = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6]];
console.log(setCombinations(sets));
```

which outputs:

```
[
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 5, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 1 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 5, 3, 4 ], [ 2 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 5, 4 ], [ 3 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 5 ], [ 4 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 6, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 1 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 6, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 2 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 6, 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 3 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ], [ 5 ], [ 4 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5 ], [ 6 ] ],
  [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 6 ], [ 5 ] ]
]
```

Which is missing combinations where two sets have items swapped and then the third set is swapped in, like `[ [ 1, 2, 3, 6 ], [ 4 ], [ 5 ] ]` so it clearly needs some kind of recursion, but my attempts so far end up with duplicates.

Comment: If the elements are always distinct (so you won't have, say, two `5`s in your original `sets` variable) then you can do something like [this TS Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N7oLPN) to generate all the combinations recursively.  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (If you reply, please mention @jcalz to notify me)